# How to get CD out of an 05 civic radio

Tags: audio

I have a radio that I pulled out of my civic to put a new one in, I forgot to check the CD before I pulled it out. The model number is this for the radio:39101-S5A-A210-M1

I found a pinout:

[image]

Can I apply 12V (and GND) to some of the pins to get it to come on so I can get the CD out?

Which ones would I do this to? (I'm thinking it would be pins 2 and 10 for 12V and 20 for GND?)

I also realize that I'll have to put the anti theft code in.

Comment: Yes and yes for the pins, but to be safe why not just temporarily reconnect to the harness or did you cut the plug off?

Comment: I don't want to take apart the dash again

Comment: That’s your choice.

Comment: It would be much much easier to build or buy a connector and wire 12v to the radio